# PHP and mysql multiple select dropdown

Tags: php

I am trying to populate drop down from mysql table. I am able to populate it successfully. But when I try to retrieve the data after submitting the form, I am not able to retrieve selected values. Can anyone help me on this?

```
$authorDB=new AuthorDB();
$myArr =$authorDB->retrieveAuthors();
echo '<tr>
<td rowspan="3"><div style="position: relative;">Author</div></td>
<td>
<select name="selAuthor" id="$selAuthor" multiple="multiple" size="3">';
foreach ($myArr as &$s_author)
{
echo '<option value='.$s_author.'>'.$s_author.'</option>';
         }
'</select>
</td>
</tr>'

enter code here
```

and after submitting the form

```
$a_SelectedAuthors[]=$_POST["selAuthor"];
$nAuthors = count($a_SelectedAuthors);
echo '<h1> Count :'.$nAuthors.'</h1>';
for($i=0; $i < $nAuthors; $i++)
{
    echo($a_SelectedAuthors[$i] . " ");
}
```

Comment: You should give us more detail ? Does you $_POST['selAuthor'] is empty ? If yes, did you checked you didn't used the GET method for your form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are submitting multiple values as an array, you need to use selAuthor[]  as the value of the name attribute.

```
<select name="selAuthor[]" id="$selAuthor" multiple="multiple" size="3">
```

Comment: it is working but if i have option as 'xyz pqr' it is just giving xyz.why is that?

Comment: no quotes around your value. '<option value="'.$s_author.'">' should work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets while setting `$a_SelectedAuthors` after submit:

replace

```
$a_SelectedAuthors[]=$_POST["selAuthor"];
```

with

```
$a_SelectedAuthors=$_POST["selAuthor"];
```

And add them into the name-attribute of the select:

```
<select name="selAuthor[]" id="$selAuthor" multiple="multiple" size="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the rest of Your code:

The lines `</select> ...` closing the select tag might not be printed as there's no `echo` that should print it. After the one above there's a semicolon!

Maybe that's a typo.